# Multiple pivots

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
+---------+----------+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| ValueId | ObjectId |  Field  | Value | Estimated | OrigValue | FromDefault |
+---------+----------+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
|       1 |        1 | 'Stat1' | 35    | true      | (null)    | (null)      |
|       2 |        1 | 'Stat2' | 2     | false     | 0         | true        |
|       3 |        1 | 'Stat3' | 0.213 | true      | 0.212     | false       |
|       4 |        2 | 'Stat1' | 513   | true      | 122       | true        |
|       5 |        2 | 'Stat2' | 31    | true      | (null)    | true        |
|       6 |        2 | 'Stat3' | 2.411 | true      | (null)    | false       |
+---------+----------+---------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/445271/2/0

And I want the pivot(s) to look like this:

```
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| ObjectId | Stat1 | Stat2 | Stat3 | Stat1_Estimated | Stat1_OrigValue | Stat1_FromDefault | Stat2_Estimated | Stat2_OrigValue | Stat2_FromDefault | Stat3_Estimated | Stat3_OrigValue | Stat3_FromDefault |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
|        1 |    35 |     2 | 0.213 | true            | (null)          | (null)            | false           | false           | true              | true            | 0.212           | false             |
|        2 |   513 |    31 | 2.411 | true            | 122             | true              | true            | (null)          | true              | true            | (null)          | false             |
+----------+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+-----------------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e84ff2/2/0

I understand how to do the pivot to get the "value" as the field but not how I can include multiple pivots and get them to be named as as Field + _ + OriginalColumn

Edit: The number of distinct values for Field are well known as can be hard-coded into the answer.

Comment: Could you also have `'stat4'`? How about `'stat5'`, `'stat6'`, `'stat7'`...? I find, generally, you're better off doing the pivoting in your presentation layer, not at the data engine.

Comment: No, the number of stats is well known (so no need for dynamic sql AFAIK)

Comment: Its not quite clear (to me) how you want to see the results. You said `Field + _ + OriginalColumn`, what would that look like exactly? For instance, would `Stat1` be like `Field_Stat1`? Also, what exactly do you mean by "multiple pivots"?

Comment: So what is the problem? There are lot of pivot example here for sql server https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/445271/9)**

Because the fields are know you can use conditional aggregation functions

```
SELECT ObjectId,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat1''' THEN Value END)  as Stat1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat2''' THEN Value END)  as Stat2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat3''' THEN Value END)  as Stat3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat1''' THEN Estimated END)  as Stat_Estimated1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat1''' THEN OrigValue END)  as Stat_OrigValue1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat1''' THEN FromDefault END)  as Stat_FromDefault1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat2''' THEN Estimated END)  as Stat_Estimated2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat2''' THEN OrigValue END)  as Stat_OrigValue2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat2''' THEN FromDefault END)  as Stat_FromDefault2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat3''' THEN Estimated END)  as Stat_Estimated3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat3''' THEN OrigValue END)  as Stat_OrigValue3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Field = '''Stat3''' THEN FromDefault END)  as Stat_FromDefault3

FROM mytable
GROUP BY ObjectId
;
```

You can also arrange the data and use the PIVOT function. Be aware value column can only contain one data type so I convert boolean to 0/1

**[SQL DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/445271/16)**

```
SELECT ObjectId, Field, Value
FROM myTable

UNION ALL

SELECT ObjectId, CONCAT(Field, '_Estimated'), CASE WHEN Estimated IS NULL THEN NULL
                                                   WHEN Estimated THEN 1
                                                   ELSE 0 
                                              END
FROM myTable

UNION ALL

SELECT ObjectId, CONCAT(Field, '_OrigValue'), OrigValue
FROM myTable

UNION ALL

SELECT ObjectId, CONCAT(Field, '_FromDefault'), CASE WHEN FromDefault IS NULL THEN NULL
                                                     WHEN FromDefault THEN 1
                                                     ELSE 0 
                                                END
FROM myTable
;
```